# What is the most expensive coffee in the world?

Tags: coffee-culture, kopiluwak

This may be a weird question, but I would like to know which coffee bean is the most expensive.

I have heard Kopi Luwak coffee called the most expensive, but I'm not sure if this is correct.

Comment: I have some that i am willing to sell.  I will charge you twice the price of what ever most expensive kind you can find.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is true, that Kopi Luwak is one of the most expensive coffee bean. The process to achieve specialised coffee is long and they are risks of failing is very high. Thus, it makes it more expensive. Read ref below to understand more. There are some beans that are produced in Penang,Malayasia are very expensive but they taste out world(honestly). When enquired about it they say because it is freshly farmed and brewed. I believe that because around that cafe, it was all coffee and other farms.

- [History of Kopi Luwak](http://www.most-expensive.coffee/what-is-kopi-luwak-coffee/)
- [Penang Coffee](http://www.thewaytocoffee.com/penang/)

Answer (score 1):

[Jamaican Blue Mountain coffee](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jamaican_Blue_Mountain_Coffee) is very expensive. According to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jamaican_Blue_Mountain_Coffee):

> The best lots of Blue Mountain coffee are noted for their mild flavour and lack of bitterness. Over the past few decades, this coffee has developed a reputation that has made it one of the most expensive and sought-after coffees in the world. Over 80% of all Jamaican Blue Mountain Coffee is exported to Japan.

I believe the family of Mr. Bob Marley have a plantation ( Rohan Marley- son?). For example, the website [marleycoffee.eu](https://www.marleycoffee.com/about-us/) advertises this story (unclear if this is actually that same expensive coffee mentioned in the Wikipedia article):

> Bob Marley dreamt of one day putting his passion of music into farming. Through his son Rohan Marley, that dream was finally brought to life.
>
> When asked “Why coffee?” Rohan Marley often speaks of his family and his legacy. He comes from a family full of passion for music and the earth.
>
> While visiting a farm in Ethiopia, Rohan began to understand that, like the music his family creates, people have a rhythm. The passion he saw in the farmers inspired him to follow his passions and create Marley Coffee.
>
> https://www.marleycoffee.com/about-us/

Answer (score 0):

Hawian coffee is expensive.  Coffee of the White House. Only coffee raised in America. Limited production, High priced labor. I had once. A 2nd rate coffee at best.  Cambodian bay coffee is good. What the price will be no idea. New coffee area new plants. Had once with some expats that just returned to here from Cambodia. So probably the best of samples. Thailand coffee aged in monkey shat is way up there. I am serious here.  Philippine coffee fresh from the mountain's is hard to beat. Coffee the more it is handled the longer in shipping, the more time from the plant. Looses flavor, turns bitter. So for best coffee not cost. It is often what day was it harvested on the mountain? How much handling. When you are setting in the bean field, they are roasting the beans in a skillet to grind & the pot is out. You have the best coffee around.